# How to solve Parsing Error in App Making?

Tags: android, parsing, sdk

I was just figuring out there to make a mobile application on the web without any coding and I found a web site for the purpose. The web site I am talking about is [Makeroid](https://creator.kodular.io).

I made an app but can't figure out an error causing the installation to revoke. The error was:

```
There was a problem parsing the package.
```

The only thing I thought of about was the **Software Development Kit** version. But that too was set to minimum version 4.4.

Comment: Visit https://community.kodular.io so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I forgot to remind the update. I just need to deal with the Package Name. The name which has to be a structure like `com.yourapp.appname` but which was in my app as the app name.